# Maximum match point saved in a tennis match?

Tags: trivia, tennis, records

What is the record of saved match points in a ATP/WTA tennis match?

And what about limited at grand slam matches?

I mean that player who saved match points finally wins the game

Comment: Simply googling for ["most match points saved"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22most+match+points+saved%22) returns some discussions of this on various tennis fora, for example http://www.menstennisforums.com/showthread.php?t=149266  http://tt.tennis-warehouse.com/showthread.php?t=5493
http://www.tennisforum.com/showthread.php?t=195755

Comment: The same search returned [this article from 2013](http://www.nj.com/tennis/index.ssf/2013/06/french_open_2013_john_isner_sa.html) about John Isner saving 12 match points, but eventually losing. The article says that: *The International Tennis Federation said the most match points saved in any men’s match on record were the 11 erased by Adriano Panatta when he wound up defeating Kim Warwick in Rome in 1976. In the 2000 French Open final, Magnus Norman saved 10 match points before losing to Gustavo Kuerten on the 11th.*

Comment: Similar question on Quora: [Tennis: Which player has saved maximum number of match points and went on to win the match in a grand slam?](http://www.quora.com/Tennis/Which-player-has-saved-maximum-number-of-match-points-and-went-on-to-win-the-match-in-a-grand-slam?share=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NOTE: This cannot be considered as a complete answer, since I wasn't able to find the record for WTA matches and also some sources I found contradict each other. But I am posting at least the information I was able to find, hoping that someone might be able to find the missing info.

**[Open Era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Era) records**

**ATP matches**

[Adriano Panatta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adriano_Panatta) saved **11 match points** in his match against Kim Warwick in the first round of 1976 Italian Open. He won this match and then went on to win the tournament. Several sources confirm this as the Open Era record. [1](http://tennisbios.com/view/tennis-atp-records)  ([1a](http://web.archive.org/web/20131106193257/http://tennisbios.com/view/tennis-atp-records)), [2](http://www.menstennisforums.com/showthread.php?t=149266), [3](http://www.menstennisforums.com/showthread.php?t=89544). [4](http://www.nj.com/tennis/index.ssf/2013/06/french_open_2013_john_isner_sa.html) ([4a](http://web.archive.org/web/20190206130408/https://www.nj.com/tennis/index.ssf/2013/06/french_open_2013_john_isner_sa.html))

**WTA matches**

I found several mentions of [Svetlana Kuznetsova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svetlana_Kuznetsova) defeating [Virginia Ruano Pascual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virginia_Ruano_Pascual) and saving 11 match points in Madrid 2001. [1](http://www.tennisforum.com/showthread.php?t=151923). [2](http://www.tennisforum.com/showthread.php?t=18154&page=21), [3](http://www.tennisforum.com/showthread.php?p=28648202).

I did not find any source confirming that this is indeed a record.

**Grand Slam matches**

In the open era there were 5 occurrences when a player saved **9 match points** and won a match at a Grand Slam tournament.

- Most recently [Nick Kyrgios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Kyrgios) defeated Richard Gasquet in the second round of [2014 Wimbledon Championships](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_Wimbledon_Championships_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles), saving 9 match points in the process.
- [Vince Spadea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vince_Spadea) saved 9 points in his first-round win at [2004 French Open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles) where he won his match against Florent Serra.
- [Christophe Roger-Vasselin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christophe_Roger-Vasselin) saved 9 match points when he defeated Marcos Hocevar at [1982 French Open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles).
- [Chanda Rubin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chanda_Rubin) saved 9 match points at [1995 French Open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Women%27s_Singles) in her match against Jana Novotná. She was already falling behind 0–5, 0-40 in the third last set, yet she managed to win this match.
- [Lucie Šafářová](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucie_%C5%A0af%C3%A1%C5%99ov%C3%A1) defeated [Yanina Wickmayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yanina_Wickmayer) in the first round of [2017 Australian Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Australian_Open) after saving 9 match points.

Source: [1](http://www.tennisnow.com/Blogs/NET-POSTS/June-2014/Video-Nick-Kyrgios-Ties-Open-Era-Record-for-Match.aspx),
[2](http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/tennis/28048786),
[3](http://www.wtatennis.com/news/article/6242162/title/safarova-digs-deep-serenas-mlk-tribute-naomis-weird-world),
[4](http://edition.cnn.com/2017/01/17/tennis/australian-open-safarova-match-points-serena/),
[5](http://www.sportingnews.com/other-sports/news/safarova-saves-nine-match-points-in-amazing-australian-open-win/1lvgl9q50aptx1sfmjzidxxwb4)
([1a](http://web.archive.org/web/20140821013955/http://www.tennisnow.com/Blogs/NET-POSTS/June-2014/Video-Nick-Kyrgios-Ties-Open-Era-Record-for-Match.aspx), [2a](http://web.archive.org/web/20170119021606/https://www.bbc.com/sport/tennis/28048786), [3a](http://web.archive.org/web/20170907213132/https://www.wtatennis.com/news/safarova-digs-deep-serenas-mlk-tribute-naomis-weird-world), [4a](http://web.archive.org/web/20170129092814/https://edition.cnn.com/2017/01/17/tennis/australian-open-safarova-match-points-serena/), [5a](http://web.archive.org/web/20190206130231/http://www.sportingnews.com/us/other-sports/news/safarova-saves-nine-match-points-in-amazing-australian-open-win/1lvgl9q50aptx1sfmjzidxxwb4))

However, on some internet fora I found claims that [Zsófia Gubacsi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zs%C3%B3fia_Gubacsi) defeated Tamarine Tanasugarn in the first round of [2001 French Open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Women%27s_Singles) after saving 11 match points. See:
[1](https://www.tennisforum.com/threads/match-points.18154/page-18), [2](https://www.tennisforum.com/threads/whats-the-most-match-points-someones-saved-before-winning-the-match.539242/#post-286248422), [3](https://www.tennisforum.com/threads/atp-rainer-schuttler-saved-10-mp-a-record.124910/), [4](https://www.tennisforum.com/threads/win-after-9-saved-matchpoints-isn-t-new-record-in-wta.403680/) ([1a](http://web.archive.org/web/20200812101416/https://www.tennisforum.com/threads/match-points.18154/page-18), [2a](http://web.archive.org/web/20200812101440/https://www.tennisforum.com/threads/whats-the-most-match-points-someones-saved-before-winning-the-match.539242/), [3a](http://web.archive.org/web/20200812101602/https://www.tennisforum.com/threads/atp-rainer-schuttler-saved-10-mp-a-record.124910/), [4a](http://web.archive.org/web/20200812101608/https://www.tennisforum.com/threads/win-after-9-saved-matchpoints-isn-t-new-record-in-wta.403680/)).

So if this information is correct, grand slam record in women's GS matches can be as high as 11 match points. (Not the 9 match points Rubin's record as claimed in the above links.)

**All time records**

All time record seems to be [Wilmer Allison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilmer_Allison)'s win against [Giorgio De Stefani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giorgio_de_Stefani) after saving **18 match points**. This was in [1930 Davis Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1930_International_Lawn_Tennis_Challenge). Sources: [1](http://tennisbios.com/view/tennis-atp-records) ([1a](http://web.archive.org/web/20131106193257/http://tennisbios.com/view/tennis-atp-records)), [2](http://www.tennisnow.com/Blogs/NET-POSTS/June-2014/Video-Nick-Kyrgios-Ties-Open-Era-Record-for-Match.aspx) ([2a](http://web.archive.org/web/20140821013955/http://www.tennisnow.com/Blogs/NET-POSTS/June-2014/Video-Nick-Kyrgios-Ties-Open-Era-Record-for-Match.aspx)), [3](http://www.menstennisforums.com/showthread.php?t=149266), [4](http://www.menstennisforums.com/showthread.php?t=89544)

Record in Grand Slam matches is **11 match points** saved by [Helga Schultze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helga_Schultze) against [Janine Lieffrig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janine_Lieffrig) at [1966 Wimbledon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1966_Wimbledon_Championships).
Sources: [1](http://www.bbc.com/sport/tennis/28048786) ([1a](http://web.archive.org/web/20170119021606/https://www.bbc.com/sport/tennis/28048786)), [2](http://www.sportingnews.com/other-sports/news/safarova-saves-nine-match-points-in-amazing-australian-open-win/1lvgl9q50aptx1sfmjzidxxwb4) ([2a](http://web.archive.org/web/20190206130231/http://www.sportingnews.com/us/other-sports/news/safarova-saves-nine-match-points-in-amazing-australian-open-win/1lvgl9q50aptx1sfmjzidxxwb4))

Comment: I do not know whether statistics for older GS matches (in this case French Open) are available somewhere online. If someone knows, whether information about number of match points in Gubacsi-Tanasugarn match can be verified somewhere, I would be grateful.