# What is the most match points saved by a tournament winner?

Tags: trivia, tennis, records

Recently [Martin Kližan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Kli%C5%BEan) won ATP tournament in [Rotterdam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_ABN_AMRO_World_Tennis_Tournament_%E2%80%93_Singles). On the way to the final he [saved 8 match points](http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/news/klizan-monfils-rotterdam-2016-final) (5 against Batistuta Agut and 3 against Mahut).

> What is the record for the most match points saved by a tournament winner throughout the tournament? (What is the record for ATP tournaments, WTA tournaments, Grand Slams?)

---

We have a similar question about most match points saved in one match: [Maximum match point saved in a tennis match?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5683/maximum-match-point-saved-in-a-tennis-match) From the players mentioned there, [Adriano Panatta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adriano_Panatta) saved 11 match points in his first round match at 1976 Italian Open and also won the whole tournament. The tournament was a part of the Grand Prix tennis circuit, which was a predecessor of the ATP World Tour.

Wikipedia list number of match points saved by Grand Slam winners [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Grand_Slam_related_tennis_records#Won_a_title_after_saving_match_points), although I am not sure whether the list is complete. (Here is link to the [current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_Grand_Slam_related_tennis_records&oldid=880471875#Won_a_title_after_saving_match_points) of the article.)

According to [this answer](https://www.quora.com/Tennis/Which-player-has-saved-maximum-number-of-match-points-and-went-on-to-win-the-match-in-a-grand-slam/answer/Abhijit-Mukund-Kulkarni) at Quora, Grand Slam record is 5 match points saved by [Manuel Orantes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manuel_Orantes) at [1975 US Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1975_US_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles). (However, no source supporting this claim is given there.)

[This article](http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/news/klizan-monfils-rotterdam-2016-final) on the ATP Tour website and also [this tweet](https://twitter.com/ATPMediaInfo/status/698995814350393348) say that Kližan's 8 match points is the most at an ATP tournament since 2001. But it is not mentioned who saved eight or more match points and still won the title in 2001.

EDIT: A recent [article on ATP Tour website](http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/news/best-of-2016-atp-comebacks) mentioned that [Félix Mantilla Botella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A9lix_Mantilla_Botella) won [2001 Palermo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001_Campionati_Internazionali_di_Sicilia_%E2%80%93_Singles) after saving 9 match points in the semifinals.

EDIT2: On WTA tournaments, the highest number I have seen is 8 match points saved by [Andrea Petkovic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrea_Petkovic) in [2015 Antwerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Diamond_Games_%E2%80%93_Singles). WTA:  [Petkovic Caps Dream Week In Antwerp](https://www.wtatennis.com/news/petkovic-caps-dream-week-antwerp) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20190206124814/https://www.wtatennis.com/news/petkovic-caps-dream-week-antwerp)) At [2001 Miami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001_Ericsson_Open_%E2%80%93_Women%27s_Singles), [Jennifer Capriati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_Capriati) lost in the final to Venus Williams, despite having eight championship points.

Comment: FWIW this link also has some trivia regarding match points saved: http://www.menstennisforums.com/11-statistics/89544-match-points-saved-21st-century.html This does not directly answer your question, but maybe is of interest.

Comment: I have posted this link some time ago [in a comment](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5683/maximum-match-point-saved-in-a-tennis-match#comment13311_5683) to a question about maximum number of match points saved in a match. But certainly, the players mentioned there could be candidates also for this record.

Comment: It's possible that 2001 was the year when ATP started collecting this info, not when a previous record was set.